# Partial search by SKU

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.4

How would I can configure `M2/ElasticSearch` and being able to do a partial search by SKU?

Searching for '12345' would find SKU XX12345.

Any solution to change elastic search query or SKU attribute setting to make it work ? I think elastic already checking in product name with like statement then it can not do same with SKU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this i think the answer is here :

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/1536

You can watch this Module to make a redirect if a product is find by his SKU

https://github.com/dianabotean/redirecttosku

Comment: Thanks, your first link made me understand what is going on and why